# Shuffling of time series data in pytorch-forecasting

Tags: time-series, pytorch-forecasting

I am using pytorch-forecasting for count time series. I have some date information such as hour of day, day of week, day of month etc...

when I assign these as categorical variables in **TimeSeriesDataSet** using **time_varying_known_categoricals** the training.data['categoricals'] values seem shuffled and not in the right order as the target. Why is that?

pandas dataframe is like below before going through  **TimeSeriesDataSet**

[image]

After the following code

[image]

why has hour of day column changed to 0, 1, 12, 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the **time_varying_known_categoricals** are NOT shuffled. The categories assigned to them are not in order like 1 for 1st hour, 2 for 2nd hour etc.. that's why it feels like it has shuffled the time series. I tried to align "hour_of_day" categorical variable for 3 days. I  noticed that the encoding for each hour matches correcly for each day so there is no shuffling. This information should be mentioned in the doc string atleast. It will save a lot of time and confusion.

[image]